# Why isn't error reporting working on drupal(6)?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

In my settings.php file (located in /sites/default/), I have:

```
ini_set('error_reporting',          E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',           'stdout');
```

However, they are not showing on the screen.

For example, I had a problem where I was missing `$` when referencing a variable and it would've been nice to have this displayed.

This has to be in the settings.php file because I have a test site and a live site and only the test site should display the PHP errors, so putting this in a php.ini file at the server level is not an option)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Error reporting page (`/admin/settings/error-reporting`) and check that error reporting parameter. Is it set just to log errors or to log and display on screen?

If that doesn't help then run `phpinfo()` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) function and see is error display allowed. If it's not check the location of used php.ini file (again be looking at `phpinfo()` output), edit it to allow error displaying (restart web server) and error should appear.